# primefaces scrollpanel not visible in Internet Explorer width given in %

Tags: primefaces

Using primefaces scrollpanel to contain a data list/table/grid to show the data. 
When scrollpanel width is given in pixels(px) then it shows Internet Explorer as well as in chrome.

But when i am giving the width and height in percentage then scrollbar is visible in chrome but not in Internet Explorer.

Similar issue i also got for the LayoutUnit when the height is given in % its not visible in IE for now i have given a fixed height in px

Question (for scrollpanel) ::
 1. is it possible to give the width and height in % and **NOT** in px.
 
2. if it cannot be done in %. can we do it from jquery code as primefaces is bundled with jquery.

Note :: Need to adjust the dataTable according to the width and height of the screen size of window.

Details ::

PrimeFaces :: 3.3
 
Internet Explorer :: 9
Google Chrome :: 21

Comment: Does giving it a min-width in px help?

Comment: @siebz0r :: I want to have it in % and not in px if possible. well using the min-width: in px it works 
Sorry for the late reply

Comment: @siebz0r I ultimately done that. since no work was working. PLease make it as answer so that i con correct it

Comment: I don't find the comment 'answer-worthy' so I'll just keep it this way. You can however answer your own question. ;-)